# Working of this non-static method (being supposedly called without an object?)

Tags: java, class

i'm quite new to Java so let me know if I'm missing something basic here..

I came across this chunk of code referencing a method from the same class. (i.e. both methods exist with the same superclass)

```
//Method (Part of a bigger superclass)
private int hopDistance()
{//Implementation Not Shown}
```

```
//The Code in Question with the function call
public boolean simulate()
{
 int position = 0;
 for (int count = 0; count < maxHops; count++)
 {
 position += hopDistance();
 if (position >= goalDistance)
 {
 return true;
 }
 else if (position < 0)
 {
 return false;
 }
 }
 return false;
}
```

Why does it seem that line 7 in the code on the bottom is referencing the `hopDistance()` class without instantiating an object? I understand how static methods can have this property but didn't understand how non-static ones could...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Java, one method within a class can call other methods within *the same instance of that class* without explicitly invoking the class name.

In other words, if `simulate()` and `hopDistance()` are both defined as methods in the same class, then

```
public boolean simulate() {
    hopDistance();
}
```

and

```
public boolean simulate() {
    this.hopDistance();
}
```

are identical.

Comment: That makes sense! Thank you so much